# Python flask Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I am using flask to deploy my deep learning model.

But when I am running my model I got this following error.

> Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL

And when I activate debug mode I got this

> flask.cli.NoAppException flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing
>   "app", an ImportError was raised:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\tab\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in
>   locate_app
>       **import**(module_name)   File "C:\Chatbot-Flask-Server-master\Chatbot-Flask-Server-master\app.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I had installed my tensorflow and the model can running well without flask, an error still appears when I activate virtual environment.

And here my code :

```
## webapp
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./')


@app.route('/prediction', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def prediction():
    response =  pred(str(request.json['message']))
    return jsonify(response)

@app.route('/')
def main():
   return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

And the index

```html
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method='POST' , 'GET'>
  <p>Text <input type="text" name="message" style="height:200px" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Virtual Environment

You mention in the post you had installed Tensorflow and it works without the virtual environment, so the error possibly comes from the fact that you haven't installed Tensorflow in the **Virtual Environment** itself. This is because when you create a **Virtual Environment** using Python, for such:

```
python -m venv venv
```

In the virtual environment, there is only the most recent of Python that you have available but not other packages you have in outside of Virtual Environment.

Solution: Activate the virtual environment, then install Tensorflow INSIDE of the virtual environment.

### Flask Request

It is obvious that when you submit the form, it is a `POST` request, but in your `index` view, you only handle `GET` request. If you don't know what `POST` and `GET` request it, essentially:

- `POST` is used to send data to the server.
- `GET` is used to request data from the server.

In your case, you want to send the form data to the server, so it is a `POST` request. All you need to do is to modify your view function so that it could handle `POST` as well.

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def main():
    // when the request is post request
    if request.method == "POST":
        // get data from the form
        data = request.form["message"]

        // do something here

    return render_template('index.html')
```

```html
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method='POST'>
  <p>Text <input type="text" name="message" style="height:200px" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

### Jinja Template

Jinja is the template engine for Python. Basically, with the help of Jinja, you could pass variables from the server side to the client side and do all the logic in the client sides. In your case, you want to pass the data you got from the front-end back to the front-end, you could do:

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def main():
    // when the request is post request
    if request.method == "POST":
        // get data from the form
        data = request.form["message"]

        // pass the data back to the front end
        return render_template("index.html", message=data)

    // message is none here because this is a get request
    return render_template('index.html', message=None)
```

and your `index.html`:

```html
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method='POST' , 'GET'>
  <p>Text <input type="text" name="message" style="height:200px" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>

{% if message %}
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

What happens in the front end? Well, it checks to see if the `message` variable from the server is `None` or not. If it is not `None`, then render the `message` variable, otherwise, do nothing.

You could learn more about Jinja [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) :)

Comment: I said without flask, so I running in python console only and the model can answer properly.

But when I deploy it on flask, with or without environment, the model show an error like those. When I running debug mode, it shows if my program doesn't import tensorflow module which actually I have install it.

Thus, I activate virtual environment. The result still error before or after I install the tensorflow on that environment, the program still not import tensorflow.

Comment: What is the error if you run with virtual environment? Because it seems like the error you've got above is without virtual environment.

Comment: After using your code I could print locally on my console to test `request.form["message"]`. But on browser still show if I didn't install tensorflow.

Comment: This is my console `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
kami  // My model prediction
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2018 08:14:36] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 kami // my model prediction
 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Aug/2018 08:14:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
kami // my model prediction`

Comment: Is it still the Tensorflow `import` error like above or different error because your server logs don't show any errors related to Tensorflow?

Comment: With debug mode yes it is, but without debug mode it doesn't show anything only the textbox. This is the case

`flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "app", .......`

Comment: There is a bug reported here with debug mode on https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397#issuecomment-338659190. So for now, just turn off the debug mode when you need to get the predictions of the model from the front-end.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I GET the variable and appears it as answer on browser.

Comment: What's the variable? The data that you send to the server - `message` ?

Comment: I'll put an edit to the answer. That's alright I was new once too.

Comment: Please fix your question saying you want to pass back the variable as well just for future reference.

Comment: It still doesn't appears anything or redirect to landing page... Yes I need the program to return back the answer. Anyway thanks.

Comment: This statement `{% if message %}
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
{% endif %}` doesn't display anything,

Comment: It should technically work. Make another StackOverflow post and put your full code up there.

Comment: Finally the response have appear, with this code `<form method=POST action="{{ url_for('prediction') }}">
    <input type=text name=message value="" maxlength="100"  style="height:200px">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >` Don't know why but your code doesn't display anything seriously. But thanks you given much clue...